# Changing Page With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to use hashes to animate from page to page. The first page that loads (home) fades in and out perfectly, but the page I'm trying to get to, test (look at hash stuff), won't animate/load at all. Why is this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Jack Cook</title>
    <style>
    #navbar ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #navbar ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #navbar img {
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    }

    #navbar a img:hover {
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      pages = {
        "home": ["Home", "This is my homepage!", "<p>Homepage</p>"],
        "test": ["Test", "This is a testing page", "<p>Testing</p>"]
      };

      page = window.location.hash != "" ? window.location.hash.substr(3) : "home";
      update(page);

      $(document).on("click", "a", function() {
        if ($(this).attr("href").substr(0, 4) != "http") {
          event.preventDefault();
          window.location.hash = "!/" + $(this).attr("href");
        }
      });

      $(window).on("hashchange", function () {
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, function () {
          update(window.location.hash);
        });
      });
    });

    function update(page) {
      $("body").css("display", "none");
      $("#content").html(pages[page][2]);
      $("body").fadeIn(2000);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="test"><img src="http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/devine_icons/128/PNG/Folder%20and%20Places/Home.png" /></a></li>
        <li><img src="http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/devine_icons/128/PNG/Folder%20and%20Places/Home.png" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the `.substr(3)` for ?

Comment: Because of the way that I'm doing the hashes, did you also see that I added !/ to the hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location.hash` will be `'#!/test'`

Try this:

```
var page = window.location.hash.replace('#!/', '');

update(page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to alter `page` passed into update to take out the extra characters. When utilizing square bracket notation, the property you are trying to reference must be exactly the string that defines it. As it stands currently, you are trying to get a property called ["#!/"] and it doesn't exist.

```
function update(page) {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("#content").html(pages[page.replace("#!/", "")][1]);
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tASFe/1/)

Comment: This doesn't make a difference because of how I substring three characters in the page variable at the top of the javascript code.